# Facebook Share Dialog not pulling description meta tag only on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile

i need to show a Facebook share dialog on my website. This is the standard code used:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
              'facebook-share-dialog', 
              'width=626,height=436');
```

I noticed that if I view my webpage on mobile phone, I will not be able to see my website's og:description meta tag being presented in the share dialog.

Upon further investigation, I noticed that:

This sharer URL will pull the description meta tag
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=google.com

This mobile version of sharer URL will not pull the description meta tag
https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=google.com

So when my website is launched in mobile, even if we are firing www.facebook.com sharer, it will still be redirected to m.facebook.com sharer and therefore description meta tag is not presented!

This is frustrating. Any solution?

Comment: We had a question here recently about that – if I remember correctly, the description is there (and gets shared as well), but is just not shown on mobile due to space restrictions …

Comment: Oh I see.... is there any documentation to backup this fact? Need to convince client..